# SCons cannot find the mingw-w64 compiler

Tags: scons, mingw-w64

I recently installed mingw-w64 and am trying to build programs using SCons. Here's an example of a `SConstruct` file I've been trying to use:

```
env = Environment(tools = ['mingw'])
env.Program('test.c')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...

scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ compilers most likely not set correctly
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scons.py", line 199, in <module>
gcc -o test.o -c test.c
'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: *** [test.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I have set my `PATH` variable correctly and can use `gcc` through the command line, so it's strange that SCons can't find it. The location of gcc is `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin`.

Another thing I find strange is having to specify tools. The man page says that mingw is its second preference. I'm guessing this is related to the above issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [SCons FAQ](https://scons.org/faq.html) (found on the project's website https://www.scons.org) has the answer to this most asked question, [Why doesn't SCons find my compiler/linker](https://scons.org/faq.html#Why_doesn.27t_SCons_find_my_compiler.2BAC8-linker.2BAC8-etc..3F_I_can_execute_it_just_fine_from_the_command_line.)?

You have to propagate your shell PATH to your build environment. By default, SCons creates clean build environments without any settings in it, such that one can guarantee repeatable builds.

As described in the FAQ, add the following to your SConstruct:

```
import os
env = Environment(tools = ['mingw'], ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
```

Answer (score 3):

Scons does not correctly detect **mingw-w64**.

By default, Scons will search multiple compilers until it finds one. However for mingw it looks for a file called **mingw32-gcc**, which doesn't work for mingw-w64.

This can be seen from the source: https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/raw/default/src/engine/SCons/Tool/mingw.py

```
# This is what we search for to find mingw:
key_program = 'mingw32-gcc'
```

You can work around this issue for mingw-w64 by create a symlink in the **mingw64\bin** directory for **mingw32-gcc.exe** to point to **gcc.exe** (run cmd.exe as Administrator or mklink won't work):

```
 c:\...\mingw64\bin> mklink mingw32-gcc.exe gcc.exe
```

You can verify the symlink from the *dir* command:

```
10/27/2017  01:06 PM    <SYMLINK>      mingw32-gcc.exe [gcc.exe]
```

With this, a simple SConstruct will just work, assuming you have the mingw-w64 gcc.exe in your path:

```
d:\test>type SConstruct
Program('hello.c')

d:\test>scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o hello.o -c hello.c
gcc -o hello.exe hello.o
scons: done building targets.
```

FYI, this is the list of tools Scons search for on Windows:
https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/raw/default/src/engine/SCons/Tool/__init__.py

```
def tool_list(platform, env):
    ...
    if str(platform) == 'win32':
        "prefer Microsoft tools on Windows"
        linkers = ['mslink', 'gnulink', 'ilink', 'linkloc', 'ilink32' ]
        c_compilers = ['msvc', 'mingw', 'gcc', 'intelc', 'icl', 'icc', 'cc', 'bcc32' ]
        cxx_compilers = ['msvc', 'intelc', 'icc', 'g++', 'cxx', 'bcc32' ]
        ...
```

Comment: Can you send an email to the scons users mailing list with this? Sounds like a bug which wouldn't be too hard to get fixed. (without needing to do the mklink)..

Comment: Ok sent email to scons dev list. Hopefully this is fixed soon.

Comment: Actually it's not broken (per say). It performs as indicated in the manpage (see below).  The current way to do this is to add the path to your mingw-w64's bin dir to env['ENV']['PATH'].  I'm just suggesting an enhancement to SCons would be to check more default paths.

Answer (score 1):

Also the scons manpage has a snippet about using MINGW:

> MinGW
>
> The MinGW bin directory must be in your PATH environment variable or
>   the PATH variable under the ENV construction variable for SCons to
>   detect and use the MinGW tools. When running under the native Windows
>   Python interpreter, SCons will prefer the MinGW tools over the Cygwin
>   tools, if they are both installed, regardless of the order of the bin
>   directories in the PATH variable. If you have both MSVC and MinGW
>   installed and you want to use MinGW instead of MSVC, then you must
>   explicitly tell SCons to use MinGW by passing
>
> tools=['mingw'] to the Environment() function, because SCons will
>   prefer the MSVC tools over the MinGW tools

That said, perhaps it makes sense to add more default locations to SCons's default search path for MINGW.

Currently it will check the Environment()'s PATH, and then look at c:\MinGW\bin

Searching both for "mingw32-gcc"

But for mingw-w64 the default binary seems to be gcc.exe and/or x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe (or i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe)?