# SCons: ld cannot find standard libraries

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, clang++, scons, raylib

I'm developing a game with raylib using SCons for building. I'm using Clang to cross compile from Ubuntu (in WSL) to Windows. My project directory contains a `lib` directory with the raylib binaries and an `include` directory with the raylib headers. When I run SCons I get this output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
clang++ -o main.o -c -mwindows --target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Iinclude main.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mwindows' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-static-libgcc' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-static-libstdc++' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang++ -o tiled_test.exe main.o -Llib -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
/bin/ld: cannot find -lopengl32
/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdi32
/bin/ld: cannot find -lwinmm
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
scons: *** [tiled_test.exe] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

`ld` can't find `opengl32`, `gli32`, and `winmm`.

My SConstruct file:

```
import os

LIBS=['raylib', 'opengl32', 'gdi32', 'winmm']
LIBPATH='./lib'
CCFLAGS='-mwindows --target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++'

env = Environment(CXX='clang++', CPPPATH='./include')
env['ENV']['TERM'] = os.environ['TERM'] # Colored output

env.Program('tiled_test.exe', 'main.cpp', LIBS=LIBS, LIBPATH=LIBPATH, CCFLAGS=CCFLAGS)
```

When I run Clang++ directly it works perfectly.

```
clang++ main.cpp -o tiled_test.exe -Iinclude -Llib -mwindows --target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
```

Comment: Side note: Those aren't standard libraries.

Comment: SCons is splitting compilation and linking into separate steps, and your working command does it in a single step.  I don't know SCons and can't provide specific documentation, but figure out how to set link flags.

Comment: As @StephenNewell said, `CCFLAGS` are used in both compiling and linking steps. If you want to set a flag only for linking, use `LINKFLAGS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. According the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25711050/5155973) by default SCons doesn't use the shell's `PATH`. The user needs to add it to the environment.

My fixed SConstruct file:

```
import os

LIBS=['raylib', 'opengl32', 'gdi32', 'winmm']
LIBPATH='./lib'
CCFLAGS='-static --target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu'
LINKFLAGS = '-mwindows --target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++'

env = Environment(CXX='clang++', CPPPATH='./include', tools = ['mingw'], ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
env['ENV']['TERM'] = os.environ['TERM'] # Colored output

env.Program('tiled_test.exe', 'main.cpp', LIBS=LIBS, LIBPATH=LIBPATH, CCFLAGS=CCFLAGS, LINKFLAGS=LINKFLAGS)
```

Comment: The libs are being found by `PATH`? or is it picking up a different `clang++` because SCons is defaulting the `PATH` ?

Comment: There's only one clang++ installed.

Comment: Setting `CXX` to `'clang++'` and `tools` to `['mingw']` doesn't seem right. Have you tried to just set `tools=['clang++']` and leave `CXX` at the default value?

Comment: @NO_NAME - good catch. I missed that. Yes mingw is not the tool for clang++.  Plus I'd add the following to LINKFLAGS and SHLINKFLAGS `--verbose` and look at the output, it should (i believe) show the paths it's looking for all the libraries and that could provide additional hints. Passing PATH along shouldn't be necessary.. ?